# NumberFormat without maximum fraction digits

Tags: java, number-formatting

Is there a way to create a `NumberFormat` instance with no maximum fraction digits? An obvious solution would be

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more definitive way of specifying that there should be no precision limit.

Answer (score 0):

From the NumberFormat API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

"`setParseIntegerOnly` : only affects parsing, e.g. if true, "3456.78" -> 3456 (and leaves the parse position just after index 6) if false, "3456.78" -> 3456.78 (and leaves the parse position just after index 8) This is independent of formatting."

I guess if you call `setParseIntegerOnly(false)` it will not worry about the precision limit, tho I'm kind of stretching the facts with this one.

Aha! here we go:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

Then again, I'm not sure what "rounding towards infinity" means. It could be that you want this one:

```
nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I don't want to round anything. I want to leave all the decimals in place.

Comment: I know. I'm not familiar with NumberFormat's operations all that much, but I think telling it not to round with RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY might do the trick

Comment: [Nope.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#UNNECESSARY)

Comment: Well, sorry then. I looked at the API but didn't find anything else that might help in this reguard